# Spark OutOfMemoryError

Tags: apache-spark

I am experiencing OOME when I try to submit a spark job that sends a message to kafka - it sends the message to Kafka (675 bytes) - the error only shows when the executor is about to shut down.

```
Diagnostics: Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
  ApplicationMaster host: N/A
  ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
  start time: 1441611385047
  final status: FAILED
```

Here's the yarn logs:

(1):

```
INFO cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
WARN thread.QueuedThreadPool: 7 threads could not be stopped
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "sparkDriver-12"
Exception in thread "Thread-3"
```

(2):

```
Exception in thread "shuffle-client-4" Exception in thread "shuffle-server-7" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "shuffle-client-4"
```

(3):

```
INFO cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
Exception in thread "LeaseRenewer:user@dom" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "LeaseRenewer:user@dom"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "sparkDriver-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "sparkDriver-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5"
Exception in thread "Thread-3" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-3"
```

On rare instances it shows as SUCCEEDED but the YARN logs still have the OOME:

```
INFO cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
INFO scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorActor: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterActor: MapOutputTrackerActor stopped!
INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with SUCCEEDED
INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
Exception in thread "Thread-3" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-3"
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code, and other relevant information, such as cluster configuration, driver/worker memory, size of data you're operating on, etc.

Comment: Hmmm... which part of the memory is drained? PermGen? Heap?

Maybe try temporarily increase one of those two memory sections and see where the problem occurs. If it's PermGen - maybe you somehow load too many class definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing `MaxPermSize` like this?

[image]

Comment: If you can host that picture on imgur, I can make it appear in the post itself for you. Don't wanna do that myself, don't want to violate some license.

Comment: Neat. Just [edit] your post with the imgur link, I'll take it from there.

Comment: Thx a lot, i've tried to help, but if he doesn't tell us  which part of the memory is drained, is difficult for us to debug